# jquery input detection after tirgger key for online pos

Tags: php, jquery, barcode, barcode-scanner

im writing a php pos system for my store, and im dealing with the barcode system now.

basically i want to be able to monitor the window, and when the barcode comes in put it in the input search box and submit it.

the 2nd part is the easy part, im having difficulty with the first part.

i made the scanner append te pipeline charecter (|) to the barcode, and i have jquery monitoring the window for any key presses that are pipeline, but how would i read the key presses after the pipeline once its triggered? maybe i have the wrong approach to this..?

Answer (score 1):

Last time I built something like that, the page had a big fat `<input>` element, that was auto-focused. Your scanner acts as a keyboard, with the exception of pasting the string in one event, rather then emitting a key-events for each distinct character. (at least that was the case with our scanners).

add an `<input>` element, focus it. When your scanner sends a code, it will be written into the `<input>`. There you can react to `keyup` or `change` events to see if the code was written completely and then react accordingly. In our case, a newline (`\n`) was appended to the code to mark its end. But I guess a pipe (`|`) would be just fine as well.